# What does this CSS code do in the nav block?

Tags: css, html

I was following this tutorial: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/html5-css3-website-template/

In the CSS file a block of code looks like this:

```
nav {
    background:url(img/gradient_light.jpg) repeat-x 50% 50% #f8f8f8;
    padding:0 5px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:4em;
}
```

What does this part do in the code? : `50% 50% #f8f8f8`

I came here after a lot of effort in searching assuming that people who know it need just 1 minute to answer....thanks in advance for any answer....

Comment: It makes the image position 50% in x axis and z axis.

Comment: You can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: After checking the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background), that should be `background-position` and `background-color` property values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background:url(img/gradient_light.jpg) repeat-x 50% 50% #f8f8f8;`

is short hand for setting multiple css attributes at once.

**I'll break it down:**

```
url(img/gradient_light.jpg)
```

This means that you set the background to img/gradient_light.jpg.
Same as: `background-image: url(img/gradient_light.jpg);`

```
repeat-x
```

means that the image will repeat it self as needed horizontaly. (Along x-axis as opposed from repeat-y). 
Same as: `background-repeat: repeat-x`;

```
50% 50%
```

tells that the pictures should be 50% in from left and 50% in from top.
First value is always x-position and secound is always y-position. 
Same as: `background-position: 50% 50%;`

```
#f8f8f8
```

says that the backgroundcolor should be `#f8f8f8`, if the picture may
not load for any reason.
Same as: `background-color: #f8f8f8;`

Comment: the main problem is in that position "50% in from top and 50% from left", here is my main confusion..

Comment: The first value is alwas x position and the second y position.

Answer (score 1):

[**The `background` property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) is shorthand for setting the individual `background-*` CSS properties:

> **`<final-bg-layer>`** = `<bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> || <'background-color'>`

In your case, `background:url(img/gradient_light.jpg) repeat-x 50% 50% #f8f8f8;` achieves the same as the following:

```css
background-image:    url(img/gradient_light.jpg);
background-repeat:   repeat-x;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-color:    #f8f8f8;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a short-hand for `background-position` property.

See [here for more infos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).